# I am getting 'Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1' when netlify is trying to build the pages of my site

Tags: deployment, build, gatsby, netlify

I am getting

> Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

when `netlify` is trying to build the pages of my site.

I have sieved through my components and as far as I can see all my paths are correct.

It seems to be an issue with my SEO component. I removed Yarn from this project but I don't think that is the issue here. It builds fine with `gatsby build` locally.

Any Ideas?

Build Log:

```
4:29:17 AM: Build ready to start
4:29:20 AM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
4:29:20 AM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
4:29:20 AM: buildbot version: a2bab682ae0761baa4d123ebd00c57be933655dc
4:29:21 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
4:29:21 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
4:29:21 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
4:29:21 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
4:29:21 AM: git clone https://github.com/AaronDukeUK/gatsby_shopify_template
4:29:22 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
4:29:23 AM: Starting build script
4:29:23 AM: Installing dependencies
4:29:24 AM: Downloading and installing node v10.17.0...
4:29:24 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.17.0/node-v10.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
4:29:25 AM: 
########
4:29:25 AM:  12.2%
4:29:25 AM: 
###########################################################
4:29:25 AM: ####           88.2%
4:29:25 AM: 
#######################################################################
4:29:25 AM: # 100.0%
4:29:25 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
4:29:25 AM: Checksums matched!
4:29:27 AM: Now using node v10.17.0 (npm v6.11.3)
4:29:28 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
4:29:29 AM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
4:29:29 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
4:29:29 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
4:29:29 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
4:29:29 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.11.3
4:30:04 AM: > sharp@0.23.1 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/sharp
4:30:04 AM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
4:30:04 AM: info
4:30:04 AM: sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
4:30:08 AM: > node-sass@4.13.0 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
4:30:08 AM: > node scripts/install.js
4:30:09 AM: Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
4:30:09 AM: Download complete
4:30:09 AM: Binary saved to /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
4:30:09 AM: Caching binary to /opt/buildhome/.npm/node-sass/4.13.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
4:30:09 AM: > core-js@2.6.10 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
4:30:09 AM: > node postinstall || echo "ignore"
4:30:10 AM: Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
4:30:10 AM: The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
4:30:10 AM: > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
4:30:10 AM: > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
4:30:10 AM: Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
4:30:10 AM: > gatsby-telemetry@1.1.33 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
4:30:10 AM: > node src/postinstall.js
4:30:10 AM: > cwebp-bin@5.1.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/cwebp-bin
4:30:10 AM: > node lib/install.js
4:30:11 AM:   ✔ cwebp pre-build test passed successfully
4:30:11 AM: > mozjpeg@6.0.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/mozjpeg
4:30:11 AM: > node lib/install.js
4:30:11 AM:   ✔ mozjpeg pre-build test passed successfully
4:30:11 AM: > pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/pngquant-bin
4:30:11 AM: > node lib/install.js
4:30:12 AM:   ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
4:30:12 AM: > gatsby-cli@2.8.5 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli
4:30:12 AM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
4:30:12 AM: > gatsby@2.17.2 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby
4:30:12 AM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
4:30:12 AM: > node-sass@4.13.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
4:30:12 AM: > node scripts/build.js
4:30:13 AM: Binary found at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
4:30:13 AM: Testing binary
4:30:13 AM: Binary is fine
4:30:16 AM: npm
4:30:16 AM:  WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
4:30:16 AM: npm
4:30:16 AM:  WARN
4:30:16 AM: notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
4:30:16 AM: npm WARN
4:30:16 AM:  optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.1 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
4:30:16 AM: npm
4:30:16 AM: WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
4:30:16 AM: added 2010 packages from 981 contributors and audited 27617 packages in 45.18s
4:30:16 AM: found 0 vulnerabilities
4:30:16 AM: NPM modules installed
4:30:16 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
4:30:16 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
4:30:16 AM: unset GOOS;
4:30:16 AM: unset GOARCH;
4:30:16 AM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
4:30:16 AM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
4:30:16 AM: go version >&2;
4:30:16 AM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
4:30:16 AM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
4:30:16 AM: Installing missing commands
4:30:16 AM: Verify run directory
4:30:16 AM: Executing user command: gatsby build
4:30:19 AM: success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.024s
4:30:20 AM: success load plugins - 0.803s
4:30:20 AM: success onPreInit - 0.003s
4:30:20 AM: success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.015s
4:30:20 AM: success initialize cache - 0.009s
4:30:20 AM: success copy gatsby files - 0.047s
4:30:20 AM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.011s
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store starting to fetch data from Shopify
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed Collection nodes: 296.906ms
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed Blog nodes: 277.187ms
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed Page nodes: 286.665ms
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed ShopPolicy nodes: 298.187ms
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed Article nodes: 319.303ms
4:30:20 AM: success Downloading remote files - 0.268s - 10/10 37.31/s
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store fetched and processed Product nodes: 508.245ms
4:30:20 AM: gatsby-source-shopify/dukedesign-gatsby-store finished fetching data from Shopify: 503.316ms
4:30:20 AM: success source and transform nodes - 0.624s
4:30:21 AM: success building schema - 0.476s
4:30:21 AM: success createPages - 0.061s
4:30:21 AM: success createPagesStatefully - 0.073s
4:30:21 AM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.003s
4:30:21 AM: success update schema - 0.034s
4:30:22 AM: success extract queries from components - 0.579s
4:30:22 AM: success write out requires - 0.004s
4:30:22 AM: success write out redirect data - 0.001s
4:30:22 AM: success Build manifest and related icons - 0.248s
4:30:22 AM: success onPostBootstrap - 0.264s
4:30:22 AM: ⠀
4:30:22 AM: info bootstrap finished - 5.940 s
4:30:22 AM: ⠀
4:31:09 AM: success Generating image thumbnails - 46.477s - 122/122 2.62/s
4:31:12 AM: failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 46.893s
4:31:12 AM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
4:31:12 AM: Can't resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
4:31:12 AM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
4:31:12 AM: Can't resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
4:31:13 AM: not finished run queries - 50.505s
4:31:13 AM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
4:31:13 AM: Caching artifacts
4:31:13 AM: Started saving node modules
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving node modules
4:31:13 AM: Started saving pip cache
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving pip cache
4:31:13 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Started saving go dependencies
4:31:13 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
4:31:16 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
4:31:16 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
4:31:16 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
4:31:16 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m55.957510427s
```